# Local changes in IntelliJ but for whole feature branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

IntelliJ provides basic view of Local Changes under Version Control bar. It is very convenient to see all places where code has been changed. Problem appears when I have a feature branch and I push a routine commit to it, my Local Changes are lost.

Is there a way to base the changes view not on the fact that the changes are local but on a kind of diff between the master and my feature branch + local changes?

Comment: Can you let us know what you want to do with / why you need such a view? Usually, you are interested in only one of the view, "local changes" --> when you are ready to commit your changes and want to review them. Diff between branches, when you are trying to merge.

Comment: This is just because when you have a big project, especially when you are new into it, it may be challenging to remember all the packages and classes which were crucial for given feature. It would be convenient to e.g. come to work in the next day and see all these 20 files which were "touched" for actual feature on branch.

Comment: I have the same problem and find myself not committing so I can see what I have touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the changes you commited (as the changed files show in Local Changes window), you just need to select the latest commit in **Log window**, then it will list the changed files in right (same as what you saw in Local changes window).

[image]

---

**To compare diff between two branches**, you can do with below steps (such as compare `feature` branch with `master` branch):

In `feature` branch -> VCS -> Git -> Compare with branch -> select `master` branch.

[image]

Then it will list the differences between `feature` branch and `master` branch. And you can double click for a diff change to view the detail changes.

> But it is just list, no markings in editor.

Since you have already committed the changes, so the list files will not show in Local changes window. If you want to list the diff files as local changes on `feature` branch, you can refer below option.

**To show the diff from `master` branch as the changes for `feature` branch**, you can checkout `master` revision on `feature` branch. Details as below:

In terminal window:

```
git checkout feature             #Switch to feature branch
git checkout master -- .
```

Comment: Thank you, but it just shows the files from one commit. Still I have no code marked in the editor, no green bars next to line numbers, no blue naming of changed file, no joint list of all changes from e.g. 4 last commits regarding all my feature branch differences in respect to the master branch.

The only thing which shows real list of changes is doing a Compare to the master branch. But it is just list, no markings in editor.

Comment: For the files listed in local changes window, it also compare with the preivous commit (not compare with another branch). And I added the way to compare differences between two branches, you can have a try. For the list changed files do not show in local changes window, it's becuse they have already been committed. If you want to list the changes in local changes window, please refer the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you *commit* your *local changes*, they're not lost, they are just promoted/labeled as a commit (detailed definitions below, in case you need them).

Typically, you would want to compare file content changes in 2 scenarios:

**Review local changes before committing** This is what you have been doing. You can continue to do so from `Version Control -> Local Changes` view.

**Review Differences between branches or commits**
From `Project` view or `Editor`, right click --> Git --> Compare with Branch --> select a 
branch to compare.

This should show you all the files which were changed. If you want to see the diff of the content which was changed, double click on the File in the tree (shortcut: `CTRL + D`). 
You can then navigate through changes and also in some cases edit the files.

This can work from Project Root, subdirectory, file, git log, etc., so play around.

Hope this is able to help solve your problem. Else, please

**Definitions**

1. **Local changes** : These are the changes you are currently working on, but have not committed. So, if you do a git reset --hard or change your machine / project, they are lost. In Intellij `Version Control >> Local View`, you can see all the files you have changed.
2. **Committed Changes**: When you are happy with your local changes, you can bundle the changes together and commit them to a branch. So, your local changes are not "lost", they are just "promoted" to a commit.
3. **Branches** : To simplify branches in git are just bunches of commits which follow each other (tree structure), normally you would've limited `main` branches (say master or dev) and many *feature* branches. Feature branches mostly need to be merged  into your main branch.